# Problem when porting to IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7.5

I got an ASP.NET app from someone who used to run it on his IIS on Windows XP (I don't know which IIS version he has).

When I tried to deploy it on my IIS (v7.5 - Windows 7) - I can't open its `default.aspx` file and I get the following error page:

**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**

> **Error Code** 0x80070021
>   **Config Error** 
>   This configuration section cannot be
>   used at this path. This happens when
>   the section is locked at a parent
>   level. Locking is either by default
>   (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set
>   explicitly by a location tag with
>   overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy
>   allowOverride="false".   Config File
>   \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config

Config Source:

82:</modules>
   83:<handlers>  <-- This is the problematic line
   84:    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>

Any idea what I need to 'fix' in the `web.config`? Is there any guide to porting apps to iis7.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the site is seen as sub-folder of another application, not an ASP.NET application on its own.

If you just put it under wwwroot, you need to right click the folder you added in IIS not Explorer and choose "Convert To Application".

Alternatively right click "Sites" and add new site pointing to this folder, or under Default Web Site, choose Add Application... and point to the folder.

When you do this, there is "Application Pool" to select. Make sure that you choose one that has the .NET version the app was created for, If ASP.NET 1.x to 3.5 you choose ASP.NET 2.0, for .NET 4.0, you choose 4.0.

Comment: The same problem still remains - I don't understand when I can change the `overrideMode`, `allowOverride` or `overrideModeDefault` flags which IIS suggests I change

Comment: No, you don't! Don't get the message so literally as the error doesn't explain the real problem. The problem is that some web.config sections are only allowed in the root of your web application, so, either a web.config was added by mistake to a sub-folder of the website, or the website is not set as application in IIS and IIS thinks its a sub-folder of something else.

Comment: Thanks, that last comment clarified the problem. The web.config was redundant. After removing the unneeded sections and using that of the default the application loaded. Although I had to manually tell IIS that `aspx` has a MIME type `text/html` which I find very strange

Comment: You shouldn't need to. This means you have another problem in there.
Try creating a new application pool and setting it to your site. Also try running aspnet_regiis -i (google it for full syntax) to ensure ASP.NET is installed correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you troubleshoot the errors according to Microsoft articles like this one,

http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

> There are usually a few more lines in that error response that points to the exact line in the config file (and hence the locked section) that has the problem. You will either have to unlock that section or not use it in your application’s web.config file.
>   For e.g., one can lock/unlock handlers/modules sections by either
>   Ø use appcmd.exe
>   %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/handlers
>   %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/modules
>   OR
>   Ø manually change value from "Deny" to "Allow" for below settings in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\ applicationHost.config
>   
>   
>   You can also configure the locking via IIS manager UI.
>   For more details refer: Locking in IIS 7.0 Configuration
>   In above error message, the error occurred on the handlers section at:
>   ”
>   This usually indicates that ASP.NET is either not installed or has corrupted/incomplete installation because installation of asp.net unlocks that section. Hence if this is the case, one should install asp.net feature from Server Manager (Under Web Server Role in Windows Server 2008 and in Program Features-> Application server in Vista/Windows7). This KB929772 talks about the ASP.NET installation failure reason.